# Как сделать нумерованный список с точками в нумерации

Tags: html, css

Нужно оформить эти пункты в таком формате:

```
1. Пункт договора

    1.1 Подпункт договора

     1.2 Подпункт договора

        1.2.1 Еще один подпункт договора

        1.2.2 Еще один подпункт договора

        1.2.3 Еще один подпункт договора

    1.3 Подпункт договора

2. Пункт договора

3. Пункт договора
```

Обратите внимание, что пункты: 1, 2 и 3 стоят с точкой после цифры. А все вложенные подпункты без точки после цифр.

Нужно сделать такой список с помощью CSS без использования JS. Варианты с точками везде после цифр или вообще без точек после цифр не подходят

Нельзя вручную проставить пункты договора, они должны проставляться с помощью CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов, который будет работать по Вашей логике.

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: item
}

li {
  display: block
}

ul>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item
}

ul>li ul li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First level
    <ul>
      <li>Second level 1</li>
      <li>Second level 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    First level
    <ul>
      <li>Second level 1
        <ul>
          <li>Third level 1</li>
          <li>Third level 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Second level 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>First level</li>
</ul>
```